# Need some help Putting it all together - From Back End to Front End

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, frontend, backend

I have finally decided to start a full stack project, a note taking app similar to [Google Keep](https://keep.google.com).

I made an REST API using this tutorial:

[Build a Node.js API in 30 Minutes or Less](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/building-a-simple-node-js-api-in-under-30-minutes-a07ea9e390d2#.wt5g2oi4w)

Only problem is I don't know how to use it, outside of Postman.

I am fairly proficient at the front end, but the back end is now what I need to focus on learning how to use. I understand what is going on with CRUD and the general idea of what a REST API is (not 100% sure about this just yet), but hooking it into the front end is still eluding me.

I have built other apps before using Angular, just not with my own API. So, I am sort of treading water here.

So you don't need to go through the tutorial.

Backbone of the API that the Tut uses these:

- MongoDB (MongoClient, hooks into an mLab database)
- Express
- bodyParser
- nodemon (only used for restarting the server on saves)

In order to get the server to start, I have to run "npm run dev" or "npm start" from a Terminal, both achieve the same thing and open port 8000. Once it is running, I can use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). Everything works just fine on the backend and things save properly to my database.

The tutorial, unfortunately doesn't explain how to hook things up to the front end. I was told that I needed to use ajax calls to get it to work. I can do that, I've done it before with both Angular 1.x and jQuery. I just don't quite know how to set up the front end.

The big thing, is I want it to be all in the same repo, rather than in separate repos. Any help would be appreciated!

(Github repo will be here soon)

Comment: You can try to follow how this meanjs generator structure the application http://meanjs.org/generator.html

Answer (score 0):

Was pointed to a tutorial that helps with exactly this!

[Creating a Single Page Angular App with Node and Angular](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular)